# Borders between columns of Bootstrap Grid not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, border, gutter

I'm creating a page in bootstrap where I'm using 4 cols inside a row. The code:

```html
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-3"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"> </div>
</div>
```

I've added a class to each col so each could have a border.

```css
.cliente {
    margin-top:10px;
    border: #cdcdcd medium solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

The problem is that the borders should be separated by the natural gutter of the bootstrap grid and that is not working.

Could you help me please? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in your code snippet. Also, your html does not include the class cliente

Comment: Mauro, you forgot the class .cliente, take a look at Skelly's answer, it's correct. And obviously, if you want side borders, you just use border-left, or border-right, but that's essentially the gist of it

Comment: Done, @ZimSystem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use another block element (ie; DIV) inside the columns since Bootstrap 'col-*' uses padding to create the spacing or "gutter" between the grid columns.

```
 <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-3"> 
        <div class="cliente"> 
          ..
        </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/71ZVOWCFWu

Comment: Thanks Skelly! I forgot to use a div inside the column!

Answer (score 7):

You can use `outline` property. NO `cliente` div is needed.

```
.row > div {
    margin-top:10px;
    padding: 20px;
    outline: 2px solid #ccc;
    outline-offset: -10px;
    -moz-outline-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-outline-radius: 10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the `outline` solution, if you want a border that collapses to the same size if two adjacent columns both have borders, use `box-shadow`:

```
box-shadow: -.5px -.5px 0 .5px #ccc, inset -1px -1px 0 0 #ccc;
```

The downside to `box-shadow` versus `outline` is that `box-shadow` may be rendered by any browser at a subpixel position, whereas outlines and borders snap to the nearest pixel. If a `box-shadow` ends up on a subpixel position, it will appear soft or blurred. The only way to avoid this is to ensure you don't do things that will cause the column to be aligned on a subpixel position.